# How to change version of patch using pcp file?

Tags: updates, patch, msp

I am using msimsp.exe to create a patch where it take all the metadata from Patch Creation Properties (PCP) file.
I want the version to change from 1.0.0.100 to 1.1.0.200 but when I apply the patch I see the version as 1.0.0.200. I have already read the article [Patching and Upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx) where it mentions about small update and minor upgrade.

But I want to change the version to 1.1.0.200? Can it be done forcefully? Is there any field in PCP file that would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used wix file to provide the version information.